# How i can optimize Xpath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to concat first 5 symbols of string with 4 last and divide them with '_'.
I came up with this, but it looks so ugly. Can it be rewritten better? I am new to Xpath, so maybe its ok(but i dont think so)

```
concat(substring(//element1/element2/text(),1,5),"_",substring(//element1/element2/text(),string-length(//element1/element2/text())-4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath v2.0 you may apply the following (*to concat first 5 symbols of string with 4 last and divide them with '_'*) :

```
//element1/element2/text()/concat(substring(.,1,5),"_",substring(.,string-length(.)-3))
```

- `.` - points to the current selected node

Note, to extract the last **4** characters you should specify starting position as `string-length(.)-3`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XPath 2.0 solution:

```
replace(//element1/element2, '^(.{5}).*(.{4})$', '$1_$2')
```

Unlike your solution, it assumes the string is at least 9 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

As for me,it's pretty OK.
But your code takes 5 last symbols. In order to fix that, I use string-length(//element1/element2)-3
Maybe, text() is not necessary, but I've processed the code via xslt.

Whole expression looks like that:

concat(substring(//element1/element2,1,5),"_",substring(//element1/element2,string-length(//element1/element2)-3))